# JETT Template engine is not supporting the List of collections instead it supports List of Java Entity classes

Tags: java, jett

I was using JETT Template engine for report generation. The JETT Template engine supports the below format of input.

```
Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ValueObject beanName = new ValueObject();
beanName.setProperty("Hello, World!");
beans.put("beanName", beanName);
```

I have tried the above and it's working fine. But in this case the type Object is referring to Java Entity classes. Here I wanted to generate a report using JETT template Engine without using Java Entity classes.  Instead I have created a collection object directly from a JSON string. My Collection object looks like:

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> packageList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Will the JETT template engine support this format?  How can I refer to the keys in the map in the JETT template?

Answer (score 1):

JETT will support this object as long as you store it in the beans Map like you would with a Java entity object.

```
beans.put("myPackageList", packageList);
```

Once it's there, you can refer to the `"myPackageList"` variable in your JETT tags or expression.

You will likely want to iterate over the two Lists you have, which will likely be done with some [forEach tags](http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/forEach.html).

Once you've reached the stage where you're manipulating the Map object (let's say it's stored in a `packageInfo` variable), you can do a [forEach](http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/forEach.html) on the keys with `packageInfo.getKeys()`, and for each of the keys, get the value in the map with `packageInfo.get(key)`. For more details on the syntax of the scripting language used in JETT, you can refer to [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html).